# SQL Server: How do I maintain data integrity using aggregate functions with group by?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

Here's my question: how do I maintain record integrity using aggregate functions with a group by?

To explain further, here's an example.

I have a table with the following columns: (Think of it as an "order" table)

```
Customer_Summary (first 10 char of name + first 10 char of address)
Customer_Name
Customer_Address
Customer_Postal Code
Order_weekday
```

There is one row per "order", so many rows with the same customer name, address, and summary.

What I want to do is show the customer's name, address, and postal code, as well as the number of orders they've placed on each weekday, grouped by the customer's summary.

So the data should look like:

```
Summary             | Name        | Address    | PCode | Monday | Tuesday | Wednesday | Thursday | Friday

test custntest addre|test custname|test address|123456 | 1      | 1       | 1         | 1        | 1
```

I only want to group records of similar customer summary together, but obviously I want one name, address, and postal code to show. I'm using min() at the moment, so my query looks like:

```
SELECT Customer_Summary, min(customer_name), min(customer_address), min(customer_postal_code) 
FROM Order
Group by customer_summary
```

I've omitted my weekday logic as I didn't think it was necessary.

My issue is this - some of these customers with the same customer summary have different addresses and postal codes.

So I might have two customers, looking like:

```
test custntest addre|test custname |test address |323456|

test custntest addre|test custname2|test address2|123456|
```

Using the group by, my query will return the following:

```
test custntest addre|test custname |test address |123456|
```

Since I'm using min, it's going to give me the minimum value for all of the fields, but not necessarily from the same record. So I've lost my record integrity here - the address and name returned by the query do not correctly match the postal code.

So how do I maintain data integrity on non-grouped fields when using a group by clause?

Hopefully I explained it clearly enough, and thanks in advance for the help.

EDIT: Solved. Thanks everyone!

Comment: So you'd like to aggregate, but what would you like to do when a customer has had more than one address? Can you give an example of the result set you'd like to end up with?

Comment: The customer info should be in its **own table** - if you constantly duplicate it in the `Orders` table, you'll never be able to guarantee any data integrity / data quality.....

Comment: I did provide an example up there - the only thing that matters in terms of which address is selected is that it must match the name and postal code. I used min because it was easiest, but as I demonstrated above I lose the record integrity that way. @marc: I realize that; unfortunately this DB structure has been given to me and I'm not able to change it. I realize that may require me to bite the proverbial bullet on this issue, but I'm hoping there's a solution I haven't thought of...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can always use `ROW_NUMBER` instead of `GROUP BY`

```
WITH A AS (
    SELECT Customer_Summary, customer_name, customer_address, customer_postal_code,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Customer_Summary ORDER BY customer_name, customer_address) AS rn
    FROM Order
)
SELECT Customer_Summary, customer_name, customer_address, customer_postal_code
FROM A
WHERE rn = 1
```

Then you are free to order which customer to use in the ORDER BY clause. Currently I am order them by name and then address.

**Edit:**

My solution does what you asked for. But I surely agree with the others: If you are allowed to change the database structure, this would be a good idea... which you are not (saw your comment). Well, then ROW_NUMBER() is a good way.

Comment: This looks interesting - let me give it a try.

Comment: Seems to be working thus far. This is actually a small part of a much larger query, so I'm going to try to plug it into the rest of it and hope it still works. The one caveat as well is that the performance has to be acceptable - I tried using a custom function to lookup but a huge overhead killed that plan.

Comment: @Mansfield: ROW_NUMBER() is from my experience not causing any great overhead compared to GROUP BY. I am also working with huge tables. I think you will see that it preforms pretty well, especially compared to custom functions!

Comment: @Mansfield: If you have problem to "plug it in", I can try to help. If you are not used to Common Table Expressions (the WITH clause), I can point out that it needs to come first in the statement, and the preceeding statement must end with semicolon

Comment: I'm familiar with CTE's. Give me another few minutes to play with it.

Comment: And it works. Thanks a lot! (And thanks to everyone else as well!)

Answer (score 3):

I think you need to re-think your structure.

Ideally you would have a `Customer` table with an unique ID.  Then you would use that unique ID in the `Order` table.  Then you don't need the strange "first 10 characters" method that you are using.  Instead, you just group by the unique ID from the `Customer` table.

You could even then also have a separate table for addresses, relating each address to the customer, with multiple rows *(with fields marking them as home address, delivery address, billing address, etc)*.

This way you separate the Customer information from the Address information and from the Order information.  Such that if the customer changes name (marriage) or address (moving home) you don't break your data - Everything is related by the IDs, not the data itself.

*[This relationship is known as a Foreign Key.]*

Comment: As I commented above, I'm not able to change the structure (though I wish I was). If that's the only solution then I'm out of luck....unortunately it's not doable in my situation :(

Comment: If and when you get a solution, it may be worth feeding back to a decision make that the current structure breaks almost all best-practices for relational databases.  And that the present and material effect of that is to make analysis and reporting of the data incredibly difficult.

Comment: The decision maker already knows - unfortunately it's not going to be feasible to fix the problem any time soon. Thanks for the advice!